# Detect Page Refresh in http module

Tags: asp.net, httpmodule, page-refresh

How do we detect page refresh in a http module ?

Answer (score 4):

### **Using the code**

```
<httpModules>
<add name="RefreshDetectionModule" type="HttpModules.RefreshDetectionModule"/>
</httpModules>
```

### **Page-refresh Detection, Step One:**

To differ an HTTP-POST from another one, I decided to stick with the idea of injecting a (more or less) unique ID in every page that gets sent to the client. To achieve this, I wrote my own class that inherits from the Stream class and hooked it to the *Response.Filter*.

```
private void application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
   HttpContext context = application.Context;
   //write the hidden field only if the request is made to the aspx-handler
   if(context.Request.Path.ToLower().EndsWith(".aspx"))
   {
     //attach the stream that writes the hidden field
     application.Response.Filter =
       new RefreshDetectionResponseFilter(application.Response.Filter,
       Guid.NewGuid());
   }
}
```

The stream-class *(RefreshDetectionResponseFilter)* basically just needs to override the Write-method. I write the whole stream to a StringBuilder and search in the resulting HTML-text for the form tag.

```
public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
 //Read the buffer from the stream
 string sBuffer = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, offset, count);
 //when the end of the html-text is read
 if (endOfFile.IsMatch(sBuffer))
 {
   //append the buffer
   html.Append(sBuffer);
   //and fire the matching for the start of the form-tag
   //the form tag contains various additional attributes, therefore
   //a non-greedy expression is used to find the whole opening tag.
   MatchCollection aspxPageMatches =
     Regex.Matches(html.ToString(),"<form[^>]*>",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
   //When a form-tag could be found
   if(aspxPageMatches.Count > 0)
   {
       StringBuilder newHtml = new StringBuilder();
       int lastIndex = 0;
       //usually only one form tag should be
       //inside a html-text, but who knows ;)
       for(int i = 0; i < aspxPageMatches.Count; i++)
       {
           //Get the text up to the form tag.
           newHtml.Append(html.ToString().Substring(lastIndex,
                          aspxPageMatches[i].Index -lastIndex));
           //get the opening form-tag
           string key = aspxPageMatches[i].Value;
           //generate the new hidden field
           string enc = string.Format("\r\n<input id=\"{0}\" type" +
                  "=\"hidden\" name=\"{0}\"  value=\"{1}\"/>",
                  HIDDEN_FIELD_ID, guid);
           //write both the the html-text
           newHtml.Append(key+enc);
           lastIndex = aspxPageMatches[i].Index +
                       aspxPageMatches[i].Value.Length;
       }
       //append the rest of the html-text
       newHtml.Append(html.ToString().Substring(lastIndex));
       html = newHtml;
   }
   //write the whole text back to the stream
   byte[] data = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html.ToString());
   responseStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
else
{
   //when the end of the html-text is not found yet,
   //write the buffer to the stringbuilder only
   html.Append(sBuffer);
}
 }
```

### **Page-refresh Detection, Step Two**

Now that all the pages contain the hidden field, I just need to look out for the value of the hidden field, once the page is posted back. To do so, I just hook up to the BeginRequest-event of the HttpModule and look in the posted form for the hidden field.

```
private void application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
HttpContext context = application.Context;
string s = "";
//Refreshing is only prohibited of the request is a post-request.
if(context.Request.HttpMethod.ToUpper().Equals("POST"))
{
    //Get the guid from the http-post form
    if(context.Request.Form!=null)
        s = context.Request.Form[RefreshDetectionResponseFilter.HIDDEN_FIELD_ID];
    //if the guid is already in the queue the post is a refresh
    if(q.Contains(s) && s.Length>0)
    {
        //refresh -> Redirect to any other page
        context.Response.Redirect("Logout.aspx");
        context.Response.Flush();
        context.Response.End();
    }
    //when the queue-size exceeded its limit (queueSize), guids will be
    //removed from the queue until the queue size is lower than the limit.
    while(q.Count>=queueSize)
        q.Dequeue();
    //since the post is not a refresh the guid is written to the queue
    q.Enqueue(s);
 }
}
```

**I hope it helps**